# Use downloaded image in Xamarin.Android Toolbar.axml

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

To be able to display a logo on the right hand side of the navigation header bar of my Xamarin forms app (in the Android case), I am using this in the Toolbar.axml file of native Xamarin.Android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/xlogo_small" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In the android:src, I am using xlogo_small image file, which needs to be in the drawables folder. Now I would have liked to have that file added into the drawables folder dynamically (from a web service call) during run-time. After a quick search I found out that adding files to the drawable folder is not possible during run-time.

I have also found that instead, in such a scenario, images are supposed to be saved into the internal memory. In the Xamarin Forms Shared project I can retrieve the logo via a web service call and save it into the: Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal directory.

I wish to know whether there is any way to refer to the path of a file stored in this internal storage directory, and use it instead of @drawable/xlogo_small within this line of Resources.axml:

```
android:src="@drawable/xlogo_small"
```

Any pointers?

Comment: So why do u need to do it via xml? Why not just access the image using c#? `string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "image.jpg");`

Comment: how can I use the C# in the toolbar.axml? There is no toolbar.axml.cs file. If the .axml file can be edited from C# could you kindly point me into the right direction?